# segmentation fault in C when assigning value

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a function for finding the max value between two double value.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double *max(double *x, double *y)
{
    double d;
    if(x > y)
    {
        d = *x;
    }
    else
    {
        d = *y;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    printf("Input two #:");
    scanf("%lf%lf",a,b);
    printf("max = %lf", max(&a, &b));
    return 0;
}
```

However, the output is this:

```
Input two #:10 9
max = 0.000000
```

So I modified the code in order to find where the problem takes place.
In `double *max`, when I want to display the value of `d`, there is a segmentation fault.
How can I fix it?

Comment: For starters, your function does not have a single return statement. Besides that, you forgot to dereference your input pointers and your function returns a pointer which is clearly wrong in this case.

Comment: You need to dereference x and y inside the conditional statement. Remove the pointer as well and just make it return the max value of type double, since that's what you're printing.

Comment: `scanf("%lf%lf", &a, &b);`. If you didn't see a warning, consider using a better compiler

Comment: it seems like you're randomly putting `*` and `&` instead of understanding what they mean